# Stuck on youtube.com/features

Tags: youtube

Pretty much no matter what I do, I'm stuck on https://youtube.com/features

[image: page i am stuck on]

A direct link to a video will take me to that video, but almost nothing else works for me. I can't view my playlists. I can't view my uploaded videos.

On March 25th, there was an unauthorized access to my Google account from somewhere, Russia, that was not prevented like the other attempts were. This user uploaded videos to my YouTube account which were (rightfully) flagged and removed.

[image: last account activity]

This has gotten me stuck in account limbo, and I can't find any way to report it or get it fixed. Appealing the videos with information of the unauthorized access got me nowhere.

I have since enabled 2-Step verification and changed my password. How do I get my YouTube unstuck from this page? I had to use my mobile device to even be able to delete the other videos that had been uploaded, because I could not get to my uploads from my computer. I've tried in multiple browsers and on multiple computers.

Comment: maybe it's pointing that your account is not in good standing & letting you know you should correct that first

Comment: That'd be a great idea, if only there was some way to get to any other page to do anything about it!

Comment: After having my account suspended, I was able to get a page to give some information. I still haven't heard anything from google about it though.

Comment: Related Youtube official help article: [Changes to account standing | Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797387?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You could try cleaning cache and cookies with CCleaner or something similar and then login with a new YouTube/Google account until the issue is fixed with your other account.